# Javascript: Alert a number with a hyphen in it

Tags: javascript, onclick, alert

I am trying to alert a number with a hyphen in it, however it keeps calculating the number instead...

```
HTML / PHP
    echo '<input type="submit" name="remove" value="remove" onclick="removeEntry(' .
          $row['Incident'] . ',' . $row['Fogbugz Number'] . ')" />';
```

This has been tested and returns the correct values to the form (checked the source for the page)

```
"onClick="removeEntry(123456-001111, 123456)"
```

Here is what happens when I try the javascript:

```
Javascript
    function removeEntry(incident, fogbugz){
        alert(incident);
    }
```

this causes an alert box with 122345.  However I want it to return "123456-001111"

I have tried:

```
alert(toString(incident));

alert(incident.toString());

alert(str(incident));

alert(incident.value);

incident = incident.value
alert(incident);
```

I cannot figure this one out :(

Comment: Show your rendered HTML, not your PHP: JavaScript is client-side.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the argument as a string in the first place; something like:

```
onClick="removeEntry('123456-001111',123456);"
```

The way you have it now, the numbers are subtracted from each-other as the page code loads.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you are doing:

```
onClick="removeEntry(123456-001111, 123456)
```

You are subtracting two numbers, not displaying a string. It needs quotes!

```
onClick="removeEntry('123456-001111', 123456)
```